# Obtaining previous months data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to obtain the previous months data,

I have tried some code that i normally use for my weekly reporting but I cant seem to get it working, I would appreciate if someone could help

```
Set @StartDate = (Select C.FirstDateOfMonth From [iCS.Warehouse3].lk.CalendarNew 

Set @EndDate = (Select C.LastDateOfMonth From [iCS.Warehouse3].lk.CalendarNew
```

Incorrect syntax errors

Comment: You have opening parentheses, but no closing parentheses. Please share the full error message as well. "Incorrect Syntax Errors" is pretty generic.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Set'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: Unless your table has only 1 row this is going to fail even with the proper syntax. Why are you using a subquery here? "select @MyVariable = MyColumn from MyTable where ....". And certainly no need to hit the same table repeatedly, just populate your variables in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax errors because you didn't close the parenthesis:

```
Set @StartDate = (Select C.FirstDateOfMonth From [iCS.Warehouse3].lk.CalendarNew --need a close paren here
```